# Spring boot + JWT error when invalid credentials provided

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I've implemented authentication+authorization using spring boot and JWT. This is how my configurations looks like.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // We filter the rest/login requests
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/rest/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(username -> userRepository.findByUsername(username).map(a -> new User(a.getUsername(), a.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER", "write"))).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '" + username + "'")));
    }
}
```

I'm using RestTemplate to do rest calls and it works perfectly if I provide correct credentials to the /rest/login api but when I supply invalid credentials it throws an error so I can't get the http status by `ResponseEntity.getStatusCode()`.

```
public static boolean login(String username, String password) {
    boolean retVal = false;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<UserDTO> responseEntity = null;

    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
    userDTO.setUsername(username);
    userDTO.setPassword(password);

    try {
        responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(Constant.REST_API + Constant.REST_COMMAND_LOGIN, userDTO, UserDTO.class);

        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

            //implement here
        }

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException httpClientEx) {
        switch (httpClientEx.getStatusCode()) {
            case BAD_REQUEST: //400
                break;

            case UNAUTHORIZED: //401
                break;
        }
        Log.debug(httpClientEx.getStackTrace().toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.debug(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:414)
    at hew.presentation.service.UserService.login(UserService.java:30)
    at hew.presentation.controller.LoginController.handleSignIn(LoginController.java:56)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: You should catch the exception and retrieve the code from there.

Comment: But if I that I will not be able to get the http status code like responseEntity.getStatusCode(). Isn't it?

Comment: Well no, because you don't get that response. The resttemplate throws an exception on any 4xx and 5xx response.